# Getting an assembly's directory from an automated test

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

I'm trying to write integration tests to cover a big refactoring of my application (I'd like to write unit tests but it's quite far from being unit testable). I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, Resharper and NUnit.

My current problem is that I can't find a consistent way to obtain the executing assembly's directory; the two methods I tried work when running the application on its own, or when debugging from Visual Studio, but they fail when running the test from NUnit or Resharper.
Here's the code (VB.NET):

```
'Method 1    
Core.ConfigFile = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\" + DRA_CONFIG_FILE
'Method 2
Core.ConfigFile = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\" + DRA_CONFIG_FILE
```

When I debug the test using Resharper, I get something like this, with both methods:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas\Local Settings\Temp\0xl3rbd5.4qn\MGClient.Test\assembly\dl3\2a373977\60b182bb_e5c9cc01\DRA.config
```

(it should be D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\DRA.Test\Integration\MGClient.Test\bin\Debug\DRA.config)

How can I get the correct path?

Comment: +1 for realizing that you should have tests in place before refactoring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to disable shadow copying in Resharper:

Visial Studio menu -> Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Unit-Testing

Deselect **Shadow-copy assemblies being tested**

Comment: I've done this, but still face the same issue. Even restarted VS and rebuilt everything. No effect.

Comment: It's probably best to ask a new question then, just tell what you have done, post some code and mention that this answer is of no help. Sorry, cannot suggest anything better.

Comment: Thanks. But it is really just exactly the same situation. Found similar questions with the exact same answer. So it seems to be the way to go, just not for me for some reason :-(

Answer (score 1):

> When I debug the test using Resharper, I get something like this, with both methods:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas\Local Settings\Temp\0xl3rbd5.4qn\MGClient.Test\assembly\dl3\2a373977\60b182bb_e5c9cc01\DRA.config
```

Switch off shadow copy in NUnit [Test Loader Settings - Advanced](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=settingsDialog&r=2.5)

Comment: +1, even if I accepted oleksii's answer (because I use R# much more). Worked on NUnit by itself.